# Disable cognito user through Lambda

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

This is my first attempt on using AWS Cognito in a project. Everything went fine until I needed to manage users with admin access, doing things like "disable/enable" with them.
My plan was to move this logic into a lambda function, which is accessed through API Gateway calls with an authorizer layer in it. Events are correctly processed but when I get to the admin operation it raises an exception stating that I'm not allowed to do that according to current policies.
I've searched a little and added some IAM permissions, which seemed to be the problem. It wasn't, so I'm stuck with it.

My lambda code:

```
const params = {
    UserPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID,
    Username: body.userId,
};

const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminDisableUser(params).promise(); //error raises here
```

My IAM Role definition (using CDK):

```
const userPoolRole = new iam.Role(
    this,
    "user-pool-role",
    {
        roleName: "UserPoolAdminActions",
        assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
    }
);

userPoolRole.addToPolicy(
    new iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: [
            "cognito-idp:ListUsersInGroup",
            "cognito-idp:AdminUserGlobalSignOut",
            "cognito-idp:AdminEnableUser",
            "cognito-idp:AdminDisableUser",
            "cognito-idp:AdminRemoveUserFromGroup",
            "cognito-idp:AdminAddUserToGroup",
            "cognito-idp:AdminListGroupsForUser",
            "cognito-idp:AdminGetUser",
            "cognito-idp:AdminConfirmSignUp",
            "cognito-idp:ListUsers",
            "cognito-idp:DescribeUserPoolClient",
        ],
        resources: [userPool.userPoolArn],
    })
);
```

Error logged by lambda:

```
"message": "User: arn:aws:sts::{account_id}:assumed-role/lambda-disable-user-ServiceRole8647FF7-E9IJC1HG9X8M/lambda-disable-user is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminDisableUser on resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:{account_id}:userpool/{userpool_id}",
"code": "AccessDeniedException",
```

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing permissions one more time, I got the error: I was setting the right policies but never linking them with the resource (Lambda). Just added that into CDK and everything started working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing these calls in your Lambda Function and you are not assuming 'userPoolRole' in your Lambda function, then the calls to Cognito will be using STS temp credentials with permissions based on the Lambda functions execution role.

If you have not done so already, try updating the role 'lambda-disable-user-ServiceRole8647FF7-E9IJC1HG9X8M' with the required Cognito permissions 'cognito-idp:AdminDisableUser'.

Comment: Thanks, callo! It was a mistake in my CDK. I created the right set of policies but never set that in Lambda. Problem solved (after a LOT of debugging).